# DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn issues getting to see if the checkbox selected

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017, windows-forms-designer

So this one sounds simple, but for the life of me I cannot see why this is not working (Windows Forms). Any help much appreciated.

I have a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn set as per following;

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
col.DataPropertyName = "Data";
col.Name = "DataName";
col.HeaderText = "Data Header";
DataGridView.Columns.Add(col);
```

This works and my grid allows users to change check/uncheck the checkbox. Great now when they press save, to save it to the db i have the following:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgUsers.Rows)
{
 bool bData = (bool)row.Cells["Data"].Value;
}
```

To read teh checkbox, I have also tried .selected and also tried to view the checkbox cell. in the following ways:

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = row.Cells["Data"] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells["Data"];
```

However none of this works. I just want to get the boolean of if it true or false.

Any ideas.

Thanks

Comment: a) selected != checked and b) the chnge must be accepted eg by laeving the cell.

Comment: *None of this works* is not a suitable problem description. Tell us how it doesn't work, what's the expected result and what you get, what exception you received, what was the message, in which line, ....

Comment: Sorry for not being descriptive enough, when I mean it does not work i mean that I cannot get the boolean value of if the check box. When it is checked all i end up receiving is a false value.  As previously stated .selected does not pick up the right boolean value as previously stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after extensive research I think I may have found an answer. I have a datagridview with numerous data one of which is a checkbox cell so users can mark/unmark the data. Now because I have a button which will loop through the datagridview rows and save the changes to a database. There is a possibility that the checkbox has not fully committed the value change. Therefore we can use the edited value as follows:

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxCell.EditedFormattedValue
```

> Gets the current, formatted value of the cell, regardless of whether
>   the cell is in edit mode and the value has not been committed

. So for my example it would be the following:

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = row.Cells["Data"] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
bool bData = (bool)cell.EditedFormattedValue
```